# Creating tables with minutes based on ranges from second table

Tags: sql-server

I have one table (`tbl_user`) with start (`start`) and end (`end`) dates for users (userid). I want to create a second table (tbl_minutes) with all minutes between start and end for each user (each minute is identified by userid). That means that in the second table I have for each user all minutes between start and end. How can this be done?

I tried using a view (see below). But the server could not complete it and aborted. Seems to be too complicated.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.view_users_woid.userID, dbo.view_users_woid.startdate, 
dbo.view_users_woid.enddate, dbo.view_minutes.datetime 
FROM dbo.view_minutes 
INNER JOIN dbo.view_users_woid 
 ON dbo.view_minutes.datetime >= dbo.view_users_woid.startdate
  AND dbo.view_minutes.datetime <= dbo.view_users_woid.enddate 
ORDER BY dbo.view_users_woid.userID, dbo.view_minutes.datetime
```

Comment: first try something, then ask a question. SO does not code for you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: First I tried using a view (see below). But the server could not complete it and aborted. Seems to be too complicated.
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.view_users_woid.userID, dbo.view_users_woid.startdate, dbo.view_users_woid.enddate, 
                         dbo.view_minutes.datetime
FROM            dbo.view_minutes INNER JOIN
                         dbo.view_users_woid ON dbo.view_minutes.datetime >= dbo.view_users_woid.startdate AND 
                         dbo.view_minutes.datetime <= dbo.view_users_woid.enddate
ORDER BY dbo.view_users_woid.userID, dbo.view_minutes.datetime

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to show us your code. You can paste in code and then hit the `{}` button so that it's shown to us as code. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the difference between two dates in minutes using DATEDIFF:

```
DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2)
```

I'm assuming you know how to run this function against your data and add it to the third table using INSERT, but give me a shout if not.

Comment: I don't have the problem to calculate the difference. But I want to create a table with the date differences for each user, based on the second table. Something like "Foreach".

Comment: If you want to *create* the table you can use SELECT INTO. So define the shape of the new table's data with a SELECT statement and create and insert this data using INTO after the SELECT. (Obviously this will only work once as the table will already exist next time it runs.)

Comment: @MarkWilliams your answer does not give any hint, how to create rows for each minute between a start and end point in time...

Comment: Sorry, I thought the OP was asking how to calculate the time difference; my second comment indicates how to create the table and insert.

Comment: @MarkWilliams, yes, but the question was not *How do I calculate the difference?* but *How can I create a table, where there is a row for each minute of a user between start and end?* At least I read it like this...#

Comment: Yes for a moment it did read like that, but I decided against that as it seemed an unusual requirement.

Comment: @MarkWilliams Why do you think that's *unusual*? Some kind of tracing, protocoll, audit, time-based statistics...

Comment: Fair enough - I've not seen that approach unless acompanied by other event data, but that may be what was required.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

This function will create a derived table of running numbers (up to 10^9) *out of nothing* and *lightning fast*:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumbers
(
     @start INT
    ,@count INT
    ,@step INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
,Tally AS(SELECT TOP(@count) (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) + @start -1) * @step AS Nr FROM N3 
          CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
SELECT Nr
FROM Tally;
GO
```

--And this is the way to use the function with `APPLY`. The CTE will first cut of the seconds:

```
DECLARE @tbl_user TABLE(UserID INT IDENTITY,startTime DATETIME,endTime DateTime,note VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl_user VALUES
 ({ts'2016-11-28 08:00:00'},{ts'2016-11-28 08:00:30'},'less than one') 
,({ts'2016-11-28 08:01:00'},{ts'2016-11-28 08:05:12'},'some minutes') 
,({ts'2016-11-28 23:50:00'},{ts'2016-11-29 00:10:23'},'over midnight');

WITH CutToNakedMinute AS
(
    SELECT UserID
          ,note
          ,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(17),startTime,126)+'00',126) AS StartMinute
          ,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(17),endTime,126)+'00',126) AS EndMinute
    FROM @tbl_user AS u
)
SELECT UserID
      ,note
      ,StartMinute
      ,DATEADD(MINUTE,steps.Nr,StartMinute) AS RunningMinute
FROM CutToNakedMinute
OUTER APPLY dbo.RunningNumbers(0,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartMinute,EndMinute)+1,1) AS steps
GO

--Clean-up for testing

DROP FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumbers;
```

The result

```
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| UserID | note          | StartMinute             | RunningMinute           |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1      | less than one | 2016-11-28 08:00:00.000 | 2016-11-28 08:00:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2      | some minutes  | 2016-11-28 08:01:00.000 | 2016-11-28 08:01:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2      | some minutes  | 2016-11-28 08:01:00.000 | 2016-11-28 08:02:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2      | some minutes  | 2016-11-28 08:01:00.000 | 2016-11-28 08:03:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2      | some minutes  | 2016-11-28 08:01:00.000 | 2016-11-28 08:04:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2      | some minutes  | 2016-11-28 08:01:00.000 | 2016-11-28 08:05:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:51:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:52:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:53:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:54:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:55:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:56:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:57:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:58:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-28 23:59:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:00:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:01:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:02:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:03:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:04:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:05:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:06:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:07:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:08:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:09:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3      | over midnight | 2016-11-28 23:50:00.000 | 2016-11-29 00:10:00.000 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and will come back to you.

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'Invalid object name dbo.RunningNumbers', although the function exists in

Comment: See below my solution

Comment: Hi @avidan, great, that you found a working solution! Just one hint: Your approach is pure *procedural* thinking, which is considered to be bad in T-SQL. It is not wrong, and - as it works - it can be just fine. But one should prefer *set based* approaches. Don't know, why you ran into problems, the above should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
INSERT INTO tbl_minute
SELECT userid, DATEDIFF(n, startdate, enddate) diff_in_minutes
FROM tbl_user;
```

Comment: This answer does not provide any hint how to create one single row for each minute between start and end...

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a trigger which inserts into second table based on changes in first table.

Assuming usertable has below data

```
userid startdate   enddate
1       20161001   20161002
```

now again assuming tbl_minutes is of below format

```
userid startdate  enddate     mindata
```

the trigger will be of below format

```
create trigger trg_test
on 
dbo.userid_test
after insert 
as
begin

;with cte
as
(
select userid,startdate,enddate,dateadd(mi,1,startdate)  as mindata from inserted i
union all
select userid,startdate,enddate,dateadd(mi,1,mindata) from
cte c
where dateadd(mi,1,mindata)<=enddate
)
insert  into dbo.tbl_minutes
select *
 from cte option(maxrecursion 0)

 end
```

Output:

```
userid  startdate            enddate               mindata
1   2016-10-01 00:00:00.000 2016-10-02 00:00:00.000 2016-10-01 03:38:00.000
```

Of course,you have to take care of modifying trigger for updates

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it works perfectly:

```
declare @user_id int

select @user_id = min( userid ) from tbl_users

while @user_id is not null
begin
    declare @maxmin int
    declare @patid int
    declare @minute as datetime
    declare @iter2 int
    declare @dateandtime datetime
    set @maxmin=(select DATEDIFF(mi, AddmissionDate, DischargeDate) from tbl_users where userid = @user_id)
    set @patid=(select userid from tbl_users where userid = @user_id)
    set @dateandtime=(select addmissiondate from tbl_users where userid = @user_id)
    set @iter2=0

    while @iter2 <= @maxmin

        BEGIN

        insert into tbl_users_minutes(userid,dateandtime) 
        values (@patid,DATEADD(mi,@iter2,@dateandtime))

        SET @Iter2 = @Iter2 + 1

    END

select @user_id = min( userid ) from tbl_users where userid > @user_id


end
```

I created it after googling and going through various sites.
Thanks to all of you for your help.